# run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global': Selecting forms for printing

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the message

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed

I'm trying to be able to have only the forms print that have been selected by check boxes.
Here is the code I have to print only the forms that checkboxes have been selected:

```
Sub PrintForms()

   If Range("PrintClientInfo").Value = True Then
       Call PrintClientInfo
   End If

   If Range("PrintInitialCheque").Value = True Then
      Call PrintInitialCheque
   End If

   If Range("Print3102Form_Page_1").Value = True Then
      Call Print3102(1)
   End If

   If Range("Print3102Form_Page_2").Value = True Then
      Call Print3102(2)
   End If

   If Range("Print3102Form_Page_3").Value = True Then
      Call Print3102(3)
   End If

   If Range("Print3102Form_Page_4").Value = True Then
      Call Print3102(4)
   End If

   If Range("Print3102_localprintout").Value = True Then
      Call Print3102Form_Localprintout
   End If

   If Range("PrintDeclaration").Value = True Then
      Call PrintDelcaration
   End If

End Sub
```

All the others work, but the error seems to be with:

```
If Range("Print3102_localprintout").Value = True Then
```

I have named ranges for all of them.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just can guess since I don't know your named ranges, nor your functions.

Your pattern seems to be to name the ranges like your functions/subs. Did you check if the range `Print3102_localprintout` really exists? Could it be `Print3102Form_Localprintout`?